# use nvm-windows to install nodejs, but npm couldn't be installed

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I install nvm-windows first, them

```
nvm install 14
```

The following is the result CMD showed:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvm install 12
12.0.0
Version 12.0.0 is already installed.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvm install 12.20.0
Downloading node.js version 12.20.0 (64-bit)...
Complete
Downloading npm version 6.14.8... Download failed. Rolling Back.
Rollback failed. remove C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Roaming\nvm\temp\npm-v6.14.8.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Could not download npm for node v12.20.0.
Please visit https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v6.14.8 to download npm.
It should be extracted to C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.20.0
```

**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

---

MY desktop uses Windows 10, CMD as administrator

Comment: I solve it by manually adding the node_module/npm from xx.zip(xx is the version )https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.0.0/ to nvm/xx.xx.xx(version of nvm)/node_modules