# Unable to install npm package

Tags: nvm, nvm-windows

when I run the command nvm install 12.11, it installs the node but give error install npm as below
"Downloading npm version 6.11.3... Download failed. Rolling Back.
Rollback failed. remove C:\Program Files\nvm\temp\npm-v6.11.3.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

any idea?
i tried using run as administrator

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73272391/use-nvm-windows-to-install-nodejs-but-npm-couldnt-be-installed can help you.